# Managment of download in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, download, nsurlconnection

I have to do a view update in parts of my application. I've a view with a view controller to manage the graphic parts -- two sliders and other objects.

I also have another class, with the methods of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. In this class, when I receive some data, I want to update the objects of the view -- how can i do this?

The options I thought of are: to pass the view controller to `NSURLConnection` at creation, or to send a notification from `NSURLConnection` each time data arrives. `NSURLConnection` is anynchronous by default, right?

What do you think is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a progress delegate protocol for your loader class and have your VC implement the protocol
2. Send progress notifications from the loader class, and have your VC listen to the notifications
3. Use a library for downloads, people around here seem to like ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ but I've always found plain NSURLConnection satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was thinking to pass the viewController (with his progressBar ecc) to class delegate of NSUrlConnection, but using notification is maybe simple, but is not a heavy operation launch and listen for new notification every time? Will i not have to many traffic?

Comment: No, notifications are very light-weight usually.