# Manage download progress in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, delegates

Good evening all, 
i'm at my first serious experience with Objective-c and i ask you a tip.

I Implement NSUrlConnetion delegate and i call this class from a principal viewController, for example name myViewController.

I want to see progress of download in viewController and i'm thinking to do semothing like this:
in h file : ...interface myViewController  where protocol receiveDelegate contains a method like -(int)setProgressPercent that return the percent of downloaded part.
In .m file i call NSUrlDelegate passing self.

Then in NSUrlConnection delegate:
in .h file: @property(nonatomic, retain) id father;
and when i receviece something: [father setProgressPercent:newValue];

is all right for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managment of download in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993305/managment-of-download-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

The NSURLConnection's delegate will be sent `connection:didReceiveData:` every time data arrives. You will presumably accumulate this data into an NSMutableData instance variable. You can thus get the size of the NSMutableData accumulated thus far, and compare it to the full size of the object being downloaded and use that value to set something in your interface (presumably a progress indicator).

However, in order to do that, you must know in advance how big the full size of the object being downloaded will be. You may be able to learn this by parsing the NSURLResponse received by `connection:didReceiveResponse:`.